# Clicking on menu item list it routes to login page

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

When we click on Menu item list, it routes to login page:

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

---

This my sidemenu-template:

```
    <ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-hover- 
     submenu " data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data- 
     [enter image description here][1]slide-speed="200">  
         <li class="nav-item" data-ng-repeat="menu in sideBarCntrl.menuList">
            <a href="#/{{menu.menuUrl}}" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                <i class="{{menu.menuIcon}}"></i> 
                <span class="title"> {{menu.menuDisplayName}}</span> 
                <span class="arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="nav-item" data-ng-repeat="childmenu in menu.childMenuItems">
                    <a href="#{{childmenu.menuUrl}}" class="nav-link ">
                        <span class="title">{{childmenu.menuDisplayName}}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
        </li>         
    </ul>
```

This is my sidemenu- main list directive calling Api Using ASP.Net:

```
 sideBarCntrl.getMenuList = function() {
            user.allowWeb = true;
            dashboardService.getMenuList(user).then(function(response) {
                //console.log(response.data);
                sideBarCntrl.menuList = response.data;
                angular.forEach(sideBarCntrl.menuList, function(value, key) {
                    if ($state.current.url == ('/' + value.menuUrl)) {
                        value.isActive = true;
                    }
                })
            }, function(error) {
                if (error.data.message) {
                    toastr.error(error.data.message);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please post your app.config route part to understand the issue and give you the solution better.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to don't attached image with hosted url. Try to blur the Url or to crop the image before you upload.

Comment: One more find is, you are having **href="#/{{menu.menuUrl}}"** backslash in template. And I believe one more slash will come from the controller through the **menu.menuUrl** too, that may cause issue. Please check.

Comment: thankq immanuel kirubaharan

Comment: thankq dude i works fine.

Comment: @immanuel Kiru , am getting this error in my console [$location:badpath] Invalid url "//".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `ng-href` instead of `href` in your case. This way you are sure the link is not broken even if the user clicks the link before AngularJS has evaluated the code.

Comment: provide me alternative solution